# cdk bootstrap fails - "Invalid principal in policy... Status Code: 400; Error Code: MalformedPolicyDocument"

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam, aws-cdk

Using the AWS CDK *(2.10.0 (build e5b301f))* I'm attempting to bootstrap 'Account-B' with --trust permissions so 'Account-A' can deploy into it.

```sh
cdk bootstrap --trust aws://Account-A/ap-southeast-2 aws://Account-B/ap-southeast-2 --cloudformation-execution-policies "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AdministratorAccess"
```

The CFT deployment (Account-B) fails with this error...

> The following resource(s) failed to update: [ImagePublishingRole,
> FilePublishingRole, CdkBootstrapVersion, LookupRole,
> CloudFormationExecutionRole, ContainerAssetsRepository].

> Invalid principal in policy: "AWS":"aws://Account-A/ap-southeast-2"
> (Service: AmazonIdentityManagement; Status Code: 400; Error Code:
> MalformedPolicyDocument; Request ID:
> 65543239-69db-4b09-a70e-52732b7620cf; Proxy: null)

It seems to me that the CFT I'm consuming has an error, then i would assume that everyone else is also running into this issue?

Actual Error:

Bootstrapping environment aws://711219499793/ap-southeast-2...
Trusted accounts for deployment: aws://864771865616/ap-southeast-2
Trusted accounts for lookup: (none)
Execution policies: arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AdministratorAccess
CDKToolkit: creating CloudFormation changeset...
UPDATE_FAILED | AWS::IAM::Role | ImagePublishingRole
Invalid principal in policy: "AWS":"aws://864771865616/ap-southeast-2" (Service: AmazonIdentityManagement; Status Code: 400; Error Code: MalformedPolicyDocument; Request ID: 72b1b1d4-b904-47ee-808c-deaf399fcdc9; Proxy
: null)

Comment: Try `cdk bootstrap aws://Account-B/ap-southeast-2 --trust aws://Account-A/ap-southeast-2 --cloudformation-execution-policies "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AdministratorAccess"`

If this doesn't help, try adding `--show-template > bootstrap-template.yaml` in the end and look for errors in the template (or attach it here). 
To make sure, are `Account-A` and `Account-B` valid AWS account IDs?

Comment: Account-A: 8647xxxxxxxx 
Account-B: 7112xxxxxxxx 

Tried your initial suggestion (swap the accounts around) just to see if it would work but no luck.

Then I tried  ```--show-template > bootstrap-template.yaml``` and nothing looks odd


Template: https://gist.github.com/thedevopsguyblog/dcc96bd210743925598d69bc23c2021c

Comment: Not swap the accounts around, swap where you put the `--trust` argument, right? Double check the account numbers in the command.

Comment: @gshpychka I have added the actual error to the description. 

Moving '--trust' beofre the account ID's didn't work.

It seems the error is to do with the PolicyDocuments being generated.

What do you think?

Comment: This worked...
```npx cdk bootstrap --cloudformation-execution-policies arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AdministratorAccess --trust 864771865616 aws://711219499793/ap-southeast-2```

Comment: I compared the output between the two commands and they are identical 
I suspect using ```npx``` may have solved the issue.